# Substituting correlated predictors with an interaction term

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression, linear-model, multicollinearity, linear

Assume you have a linear model with two predictors $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2$ and you find out that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are correlated and VIFs are over 5.

I read that you can remove the co-linearity by either removing one of the predictors or combining them. This sounds reasonable to me but I am a bit confused about the "combining" approach. Is any type of combination acceptable? For instance, can I combine them as an interaction term ($y=\beta_0 + \beta_1x_1x_2$)? According to the hierarchy principle this shouldn't be done but is it acceptable in this scenario? In my particular case this combination improves $R^2$ by 4%.